# Simple address book in C++ - follow-up

Tags: c++, object-oriented

After posting my original address book program I took the responses and edited my code. I have used every suggestion given, the code works great, and now I am looking for further review and suggestions from the Code Review community.

**Parent class (`Person`):**

```
//parent class
#ifndef PERSON
#define PERSON
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Person
{
public:
    //input person variable
    std::istream& read(std::istream&, Person &p1);
    //output person variable
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os, const Person &p1);
    //comparison operator
    bool operator<(const Person&) const;
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};

#endif
```

**`Person` member functions:**

```
#include "Person.h"

//input for address book person element
std::istream& Person::read(std::istream& in, Person &p1) {
    std::cin >> p1.name;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::getline(std::cin, p1.address);
    return in;
}

//operator for address book person element
std::ostream& Person::print(std::ostream& os, const Person &p1) {
    os << "Name: " << p1.name << "\nAddress: " << p1.address << "\n\n";
    return os;
}

bool Person::operator<(const Person& other) const {
    return name < other.name;
}
```

**Child class (Address Book):**

```
//child class
#ifndef ADDRESS_BOOK
#define ADDRESS_BOOK
#pragma once

#include "Person.h"

class Address_book : public Person
{
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Address_book&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Address_book&);
public:
    //set vector size to match appropriate number of entries
    void num_of_ent(int, Address_book&);
    void Address_book::sort(Address_book&,int);

private:
    std::vector<Person> add_book;
};

#endif
```

**Address book member functions:**

```
#include "Address_book.h"

//sets vector size, creates person elements of vector
void Address_book::num_of_ent(int entries, Address_book& abook) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entries; ++i) {
            Person p;
        abook.add_book.push_back(p);
    }
}

//fills address book
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Address_book& abook) {
    for (int i = 0; i < abook.add_book.size(); ++i) {
        abook.add_book[i].read(in, abook.add_book[i]);
    }
    return in;
}

//sort address book
void Address_book::sort(Address_book& abook) {
    std::sort(abook.add_book.begin(), abook.add_book.end());
}
//prints contents of address book
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Address_book& abook) {
    for (int i = 0; i < abook.add_book.size(); ++i) {
        abook.add_book[i].print(os, abook.add_book[i]);
    }
    return os;
}
```

**Main:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Address_book.h"
#include "Person.h"

void pause();

int main() {

    int entries = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter number of entries to go in addressbook: ";
    std::cin >> entries;

    Address_book abook1;
    abook1.num_of_ent(entries, abook1);

    //input into addressbook
    std::cout << "Enter the name, followed by the address:\n";
    std::cin >> abook1;
    //sort addressbook
    abook1.sort(abook1, entries);

    //output addressbook
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << abook1;

    pause();
}

void pause() {
    std::string pause;
    std::cout << "Press any key followed by enter to continue...";
    std::cin >> pause;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Misuse of inheritance

The huge, glaring problem I see with this code can be shown in one line:

```
class Address_book : public Person
```

This looks to me like a *completely* broken architecture. As a rule, public inheritance should follow the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP), and this isn't even close<sup>1</sup>.

Before Barbara Liskov formulated the substitution principle, the usual phrasing was that public inheritance should reflect an "Is-a" relationship. The LSP attempts to...tighten that a little to deal with a few odd cases like circles vs. ellipses, where you can say a circle is a specific case of an ellipse, but (since you can't always substitute a circle where an ellipse is required) you shouldn't normally use public inheritance.

In this case, however, we don't need the more careful formulation. An address book isn't a person, and isn't really even anything like a person. We don't need to look much further to see that this is use (abuse?) of inheritance is problematic at best.

#### Consistent interface

I'd also change the interface a little bit. Right now, you have `read` and `write` member functions for `Person`, and `operator<<` and `operator>>` for an address book.

I'd prefer to change this so the public interface is more consistent. Since the (more or less) standard way to do formatted I/O is to use `operator<<` and `operator>>`, I'd use those for both classes.

#### Resizing

Right now, to resize your vector, you have code like:

```
//sets vector size, creates person elements of vector
void Address_book::num_of_ent(int entries, Address_book& abook) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entries; ++i) {
            Person p;
        abook.add_book.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

I'm not fond of the name (at first blush, the name sounds more like it should be retrieving the current number of entries). I'd also prefer to use `vector`'s `resize()` member instead. Finally, a member function that's going to modify an object should *normally* modify the object of which it's a member, not have some other object passed to it to modify.

```
void Address_book::resize(int entries) {
    add_book.resize(entries);
}
```

#### Size type

That brings us to the next point: the type for the size of a container is preferably `container_type::size_type` or if that's not easily available, you can usually use `size_t` as a fair approximation. So that means the `resize` should really be changed to:

```
void Address_book::resize(size_type entries) {
    add_book.resize(entries);
}
```

...where `size_type` is something like:

```
typedef vector<Person>::size_type size_type;
```

...or:

```
using size_type = vector<Person>::size_type;
```

#### formatting of output

A fairly minor point is that by convention writing an object to the stream should only write the content of that object to the stream, not write a delimiter that separates that object from the next. For example, here:

```
//operator for address book person element
std::ostream& Person::print(std::ostream& os, const Person &p1) {
    os << "Name: " << p1.name << "\nAddress: " << p1.address << "\n\n";
    return os;
}
```

...we really want to get rid of the trailing new-lines, and leave that to the client code.

```
std::ostream& Person::print(std::ostream& os, const Person &p1) {
    os << "Name: " << p1.name << "\nAddress: " << p1.address;
    return os;
}
```

Then we might use it something like this:

```
std::copy(my_book.begin(), my_book.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<Person>(std::cout, delimiter));
```

...and to get the same format, we'd have `delimiter = "\n\n";`, but if we wanted the output single-spaced, it'd be `"\n"`, and so on.

---

<sup>1. Nor do I see any indication that this might be an exception to the rule.</sup>

Comment: thank you for your reply, so if i get rid of the misuse of public inheritence which i will do, is there anything else besides that that should be improved on? -Thank you.

Comment: So should i completly separate the classes? Is that what you are suggesting? Sorry im still new to this.

Comment: Hi @chris360. Sorry, I had to leave for a while (have kids who needed to hunt Easter eggs). I've added a few more points.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! You've given me a lot of info and i really appreciate it. Im going to fix my code up and repost it when i get it finished. Thanks again!